# Noise in velocity of cursor that is recorded in C#

Tags: c#, plot, cursor, noise

While I am recording cursor position using C#, I move my the cursor on a circular path in my monitor. Here is the code that I use to record the cursor and also the elapsed time:

```
    Stopwatch swTime = new Stopwatch();
    private StreamWriter swRecorder;

    private void start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        swRecorder = new StreamWriter("cursor.txt");
        swTime.Start();
        timer1.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void stop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        timer1.Enabled = false;
        swTime.Stop();
        swRecorder.Close();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strNewLine = swTime.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds.ToString();
        strNewLine = strNewLine + "," + Cursor.Position.X.ToString();
        swRecorder.WriteLine(strNewLine);
    }
```

If I plot the recorder position (X component) of the cursor versus time, I will get the following plot:

[image]

Then I measure the velocity (DeltaX/DeltaT) and again plot it versus time. Then I will get the following plot:

[image]

Now my question is: why the velocity is noisy/jagged?

Comment: Because you are not moving the cursor at a steady speed?

Comment: Could it be due to the tick length of the timer itself? edit: see @dlxeon very precise answer below.

Comment: @RyanPeters The plots are drawn against the time of the recording. So, the tick length can't be the issue!

Comment: @PaulF I am not moving the cursor at a steady speed and that's why you see the big changes in velocity in the form of sinus. However, I am talking about the tiny fluctuation with high frequency that can't possibly be because of hand movements.

Comment: Remember your high-school math, you are doing differentiation.  Every time there's a bump or wrinkle in the input data you can expect a peak or valley.  But the biggest source of error is not visible, you hid it by drawing a smooth curve through the mouse points.  Big problem is that you can only get integer values, it is not *actually* a smooth curve.  You always have a +/- 0.5 system error.  And differentiating a step-wise changes produces an infinite velocity.  It is only kept in check by your choice of dT.  What you must do is *first* interpolate a smooth function through the data.

Answer (score 1):

I think primary reason is that you are not doing precise circles with constant speed. 
In addition to this I think following is possible:

- Windows Forms timer is not guaranteed to be called exactly every xx milliseconds. So you'll get new measurements over slightly different time periods
- Mouse sensor precision (DPI) can cause coordinates to be slightly different from real mouse position
- Standard non-gaming USB mouse has typically 125Hz refresh rate (get value from mouse once in 8ms). It means Windows itself gets value with some delay. Almost all gaming mice have 1000Hz refresh rate (1ms delay).

Comment: I don't believe speed being not constant is the issue. The fluctuations that are like noise are happening in around every 20-30 ms. When a human move his/her hand, the changes in speed can't possibly be this fast with high frequency. The changes in speed due to the hand movements are those following a sinus form (in the second plot) and not the tiny noises.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely because the chart's **automatic scaling** is enlarging the data to the max and thus the small speed differences look mighty large.

Also chosing a `line` graph is not really a good choice, as it produces the illusion of 'knowing' about the data between the data points. A scatter plot (`points`) is more appropriate, imo.